# Golang mapping JSON into struct

Tags: json, go

I have a struct as below:

```
type Item struct {
  ID         int16 `json:"id"`
  SubItem    *Item `json:"sub_item"`
}
```

And the JSON as below:

```
{
  "id": 100,
  "sub_item": 110
}
```

If I use `json.Unmarshal(json, &item)`, the json field `sub_item` is the `Item.ID`, so cannot mapping into struct.

I want to find the SubItem by the subitem id before json unmarshal, but I don't know how to do it. Or is there any way to resolve this problem? thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want to unmarshal object like linked-list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*Item` is a golang pointer to a struct. It cannot contain a `int16` (that is a "pointer" in your json semantic).

You can handle this programmatically *after* Unmarshaling.

Struct must be:

```
type Item struct {
    ID         int16 `json:"id"`
    SubItem    *Item
    SubItemInt int16 `json:"sub_item"`
}
```

and then you should do something like this:

```
items := make(map[int16]*Item)
[...]
for k := range items {
    items[k].SubItem = items[items[k].SubItemInt]
}
```